# convert tuple to dict and accessing its values

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, key

```
inputTuple = ({'mobile': '91245555555', 'email': 'xyz@gmail.com', 'name': 'xyz', 'app_registration': 1},)
print(type(inputTuple))  # <class 'tuple'>

my_dict = dict(inputTuple)
print(my_dict)  #ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required
mobile = my_dict.get("mobile")
email = my_dict.get("email")
name = my_dict.get("name")

print(mobile)
print(email)
print(name)
```

**how to get now each data from this tuple, first how to convert this to dict, i need to convert to dict and have to get all the key pair values,and not  by using index values**
**Thanks for the answers**

Comment: You mean `dict(*inputTuple)`?

Comment: my_dict = inputTuple[0]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
inputTuple = ({'mobile': '91245555555', 'email': 'xyz@gmail.com', 'name': 'xyz', 'app_registration': 1})
```

In the question the inputTuple value ended with 'comma' which will make it as tuple and if we remove that it will be dict. and it worked in below way after change in question.

```
 mobile = data.get("mobile", None)
```

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want

```
my_dict = inputTuple[0]
data = my_dict['mobile']
print(data)
```